# ffmpeg - cubic-bezier for drawtext movement

Tags: ffmpeg

as you know, we can add "time" variable to "x" parameter on Drawtext, to move the text; usually we have linear transformation ( t+100 ), buy I'd like to reproduce a kind of "Cubic Bezier" effect to my text, while it cames into the scene.

This is a final effect:

http://cubic-bezier.com/#.6,.01,.4,.99

Has someone ever tried to reproduce this kind of effect?!!